# How to upload files in REST in a bulked way?

Tags: rest

Let's say now I post data about cars in a bulked way:

```
{
cars: [
{"brand":"opel","plateNum":"1234"},
{"brand":"bmw","plateNum":"2345"},
{"brand":"audi","plateNum":"3456"}
]
}
```

Now a new feature should be implemented namely uploading multiple files(like usermanual,registration certificate..etc) for each.

If I wouldn't use bulk upload I would just use a "multipart/form-data" with a json + files and it would be evident which files belongs to which car:

```
   car: {"brand":"opel","plateNum":"1234"}
   usermanual: file.jpg
   ..etc
```

How to do it in a bulked way? The only solution came to my mind is to introduce a unique id for the cars and append it as a suffix to the corresponding filenames, but I want to avoid that.

Is there a way to group somehow the uploaded files by an id in multipart/form-data? like:

```
cars: [
{"id":1,"brand":"opel","plateNum":"1234"},
{"id":2,"brand":"bmw","plateNum":"2345"},
{"id":3,"brand":"audi","plateNum":"3456"}
]
filegroup1:
  usermanual:file.jpg
  ..etc
filegroup2:
  usermanual:file.jpg
  ..etc
filegroup3:
  usermanual:file.jpg
  ..etc
```

Exists something like this in REST? Or what is the common practice to upload files to a bulked json?